# Solar charging a 18650 Battery ( MPPT vs TP4065 )

Tags: solar-energy, mppt

Most my solar project which includes ESP8266, a sensor and solar+ battery + MPPT charging module.
In some tutorials I saw a use of TP4065 [as in this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/power-esp32-esp8266-solar-panels-battery-level-monitoring/)

While MPPT optimizes charge for varying voltages ( as a function of sunlight ), TP4065 is a standard LiPo battery charger ( assuming for contant voltage ).

I would like to hear pros and cons for each use.

THNX

Comment: TP4065 should be cheaper and optimilized for Lion and LiPo battery. MPPT is more versatile.

Comment: MPPT just gives you vastly superior efficiency performance in suboptimal conditions, sometimes in normal conditions too.  If it has built in charging, note that you should never charge a lithium ion battery except with a charger designed for that type and capacity.